# How do I make a scatter plot from CSV data using Python and Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, scatter-plot

I am using Python 3.5 and Matplotlib. I have less than a month's experience with python but I have data in a CSV file I'm needing to graphically represent. It only has 3 columns: weight (pounds), height (inches), BMI. It's [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppgp1uit1idm0ef/BMIdata.csv?dl=0) if you want to see it. I just want to make a height vs weight scatter plot with different symbols and colors for each of the 4 BMI groups (BMI greater than 20, greater than 25 but less than or equal to 30, greater than 20 but less than or equal to 25, and less than 20).

Here is what I have so far. I feel like there is a more efficient way of doing this. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
 `import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data2 = pd.read_csv('BMIData.csv')

bmi1 = data2[(data2.BMI<20)]
bmi2 = data2[(data2.BMI>20) & (data2.BMI<=25)]
bmi3 = data2[(data2.BMI>25) & (data2.BMI<=30)]
bmi4 = data2[(data2.BMI>30)]

bmi1h = bmi1.height.values
bmi1w = bmi1.weight.values

bmi2h = bmi2.height.values
bmi2w = bmi2.weight.values

bmi3h = bmi3.height.values
bmi3w = bmi3.weight.values

bmi4h = bmi4.height.values
bmi4w = bmi4.weight.values

plt.scatter(bmi1h, bmi1w, color='r', marker='*', label='Less than 20')
plt.scatter(bmi2h, bmi2w, color='b', marker='^', label='20 to 25')
plt.scatter(bmi3h, bmi3w, color='c', marker='x', label='25 to 30')
plt.scatter(bmi4h, bmi4w, color='m', label='Greater than 30')

plt.xlabel('Height (in)')
plt.ylabel('Weight (lb)')
plt.title('BMI Data')
plt.legend()

plt.axis([63,80,100,400])


plt.savefig('BMIplot.png', dpi=300)

plt.show()
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your CSV file as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = open('BMIdata.csv','r')
readings = file.readlines()
readings.pop(0)
height = []
weight = []
BMI = []
for reading in readings:
    h, w,B = reading.strip('\r\n').split(',')
    height.append(h)
    weight.append(w)
    BMI.append(B)
```

The lists: height, weight, BMI will contain the respective data without the table heading.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about doing this. One way I frequently use is to construct boolean indexer arrays, instead of copies of the DataFrame. See the documentation on [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). Your code is then simplified to:

```
data2 = pd.read_csv('BMIData.csv')

bmi1 = (data2.BMI<20)
bmi2 = (data2.BMI>20) & (data2.BMI<=25)
bmi3 = (data2.BMI>25) & (data2.BMI<=30)
bmi4 = (data2.BMI>30)

plt.scatter(data2.loc[bmi1,'height'], data2.loc[bmi1,'weight'], color='r', marker='*', label='Less than 20')
plt.scatter(data2.loc[bmi2,'height'], data2.loc[bmi2,'weight'], color='b', marker='^', label='20 to 25')
plt.scatter(data2.loc[bmi3,'height'], data2.loc[bmi3,'weight'], color='c', marker='x', label='25 to 30')
plt.scatter(data2.loc[bmi4,'height'], data2.loc[bmi4,'weight'], color='m', label='Greater than 30')
```

Another way would be to create an additional column to your DataFrame, and write a code (1,2,3,4 or 'bmi1', 'bmi2', etc.) then use `groupby()` in pandas ([Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)) to extract each of the groups. You could also use [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/), which is very handy to make these kinds of operations on data that can be split into groups.